# Fast Query with Left Join To Get Record With Latest Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

For this problem, I have 2 main existing postgres tables I am working with.  The first table is named **client**, the second table is named **task**.

A single client can have multiple tasks, each with it's own scheduled_date and scheduled_time.

I'm trying to run a query that will return a list of all clients along with the date/time of their latest task.

Currently, my query works and looks something like this...

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    t1.scheduled_time||' '||t1.scheduled_time::timestamp AS latest_task_datetime
FROM
    client c
LEFT JOIN
    task t1 ON t1.client_id = c.client_id
LEFT JOIN
    task t2 ON t2.client_id = t1.client_id AND ((t1.scheduled_date||' '||t1.scheduled_time)::timestamp < (t2.scheduled_date||' '||t2.scheduled_time)::timestamp) OR ((t1.scheduled_date||' '||t1.scheduled_time)::timestamp = (t2.scheduled_date||' '||t2.scheduled_time)::timestamp AND t1.task_id < t2.task_id);
```

The problem I'm having is the actual query I am working with deals with a lot more other tables (7+ tables), and every table has a lot of data in them, so because of the two left joins shown above, it is slowing down the execution of the query from 4 seconds to almost 45 seconds, which of course is very bad.

Does anyone know a possible faster way to write this query to run more efficiently?

A question I think you might initially have after seeing this is why I have scheduled_date and scheduled_time as separate columns?  Why not have it as just a single timestamp column?  The answer to that is this is an existing table that I can't change, at least not easily without requiring a lot of work making the changes in the entire server to support it.

Edit: Not quite the solution, but I just ended up doing it a different way. (See my comment below)

Comment: have you put an index on all fields in the joins?

Comment: The result is there is no way to make the query run considerably faster. So Instead, I just created a new column in the client table named latest_task_on and made sure it was updated every time a task was created, updated, closed, or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get multiple columns of information from different tables -- but one row for each client and his/her latest task, then you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.client_id) c.*, t.*
FROM client c LEFT JOIN
     task t
     ON t.client_id = c.client_id
ORDER BY c.client_id, t.scheduled_date desc, t.scheduled_time desc;
```